# How to pass variable name into method (to log it)?

Tags: java, android

I'm beginner with first question. I want to have method allowing to quickly log many parameters, so I want to have in log line variable name and value.
Example of usage -- I put what I want to log as arguments:

```
fastLog(
        animation.getAnimatedValue(),
        animation.getDuration(),
        animation.getInterpolator(),
        animation.getListeners(),
        animation.getRepeatCount()
            );
```

And this method below gives me values and it works, but how to log names as well like "animation.getAnimatedValue()" next to values ?

```
private void fastLog(Object... obj) {

        for(Object o : obj) {
            String s = String.valueOf(o);
            Log.d("FastLog", s);
        }
}
```

So the result would be:

```
Fastlog 1000 animation.getAnimatedValue()
(...)
```

Comment: `fastlog("animation.getAnimatedValue()",...`

Comment: Just have the animation class implement ```toString``` that returns this log string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
private void fastLog(Object... obj) {
    String log = "";
    for(Object o : obj) {
        log += o + " ";
    }
    Log.d("FastLog", log);
}
```

Usage : 
`fastLog("Value1", value1, "value2", value2);`

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with that set up. Either change the parameters to something like:

```
private final static Logger LOG
            = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());    
private void fastLog(Map<String, Object> log) {

        for(Entry <String, Object> o : log) {
            LOG.info("FastLog {0}:{1}", new Object[]{o.getKey(), o.getValue()});
        }
}
```

I was not clear what do you use for logger, the above code uses java.util.logging.Logger.

Answer (score 0):

For instance you can create pairs `Pair<Object, String>` or `SimpleMapEntry<>`-s and provide them as args instead of just objects. Place desired method name to their`second` then you can log method along with object value using `String.format()`